# Wrong Logic of Auto Incrementing of string?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

Below these code I'm getting the wrong output in incrementing the string value in my Database column "SupplierID". I'm transferring the string value to my lbl_id in ADDSupplier Form and That's what i used to insert value to my "SupplierID".

Desired Output:

- SPPL-0001
- SPPL-0002
- SPPL-0003
  etc

Currently Output (Below these code):

- SPPL-0001
- SPPL-00012
- SPPL-00013
  etc

NOTE: When i repeat inserting data i get the currently output that i stated above but when i restart the program and the last inserted value, For example is SPPL-00013. When i open my adding form, lbl_id display the id as SPPL-0004. If i continue, it become SPPL-00045.

PS: SupplierID is varchar(50) in my database and also PRIMARY_KEY

[These image shows the wrong output of mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2gzs.png)

What i want to get help with is to correct my logic and get that desired output. Please help me. Thank you

```
public partial class SIMSSupplier : UserControl
{
    ADDSupplier supply;
    public SIMSSupplier()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    public string ID = "SPPL-000";
         public void GenerateAutoID()
    {
        using (var con = SQLConnection.GetConnection())
        {
            using (var select = new SqlCommand("Select Count(SupplierID) from admin_supplier", con))
            {
                int i = Convert.ToInt32(select.ExecuteScalar());
                i++;
                supply.lbl_id.Text = ID + i.ToString();
            }

        }
    }
    private void btn_register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        supply = new ADDSupplier(this);
        supply.Show();
        GenerateAutoID();
    }
}


 public partial class ADDSupplier : MetroForm
{
    SIMSSupplier _view;
    public ADDSupplier(SIMSSupplier _view)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this._view = _view;

    }

   string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM-dd-yyyy");
   private void btn_ok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _view.ID = lbl_id.Text;
        using (var con = SQLConnection.GetConnection())
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_name.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_contact.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(cbox_remark.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_address.Text))
            {
                CustomNotifcation.Show("Please input the required fields", CustomNotifcation.AlertType.warning);
            }
            else
            {
                using (var select = new SqlCommand("Insert into admin_supplier (SupplierID, Companyname, Contactnumber, Date, Remarks, Address) Values (@SupplierID, @Companyname, @Contactnumber, @Date, @Remarks, @Address)", con))
                {
                    select.Parameters.Add("@SupplierID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lbl_id.Text;
                    select.Parameters.Add("@Companyname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_name.Text;
                    select.Parameters.Add("@Contactnumber", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_contact.Text;
                    select.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = date;
                    select.Parameters.Add("@Remarks", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cbox_remark.Text;
                    select.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_address.Text;
                    select.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    CustomMessage.Show("Message: Supplier successfully added!", CustomMessage.Messagetype.Success2);
                    _view._Supplier();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about `supply.lbl_id.Text = "SPPL-" + i.ToString("0000");`? Or in newer versions: `supply.lbl_id.Text = $"SPPL-{i:0000}";` -- see also: [custom numeric format](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)

Comment: Yes for your 1st question and what do you mean by just a convenience ?

Comment: @Corak Let me try this thank you :)

Comment: I was wondering if it was just for display purposes (i.e. you have to prefix supplier IDs with `SPPL-` for user display). If that were the case, I'd just use autoincrementing IDs in the database and format it for display.

Comment: You'll run into similar problems, once you have 10000+ items in that table, though. ^_^

Comment: Your design is very problematic. What happens when you get 10,000 rows? Suddenly your logic is broken. I would use an identity column instead of rolling your own. Then create a computed column if you want to munge that prefix onto the beginning.

Comment: @Corak Great ! , It solved my problem. Thank you

Comment: Let the data base do the `auto increment` for you. If every row has `SPPL-` as a prefix, it is redundant nevertheless. Use a number type and add it (the prefix) to a not mapped property or just add it in your view if its relevant.

Comment: @Corak Do you have a better suggestion when items is up to that ?, but to my client business 30+ is their maximum supplier though.

Comment: Don't listen to your client when they say strange things like 'this will never happen' :D

Comment: @SeanLange Is it not recommended to use string with numbers as a unique ID ?

Comment: @Anonymous - well, `int.MaxValue.ToString()` has 10 characters, so if it's possible, See if an ID like `"SPPL-0000000001"` would be okay...

Comment: Well if you stick the same prefix on that isn't exactly doing anything to help uniqueness, it is just slapping a few characters at the beginning. And any roll your own type of identity is fraught with issue.

Comment: How about using an numeric ID for your referenz model, but also using a string property to hold that suppliers identifier: `[NotMapped] public string SupIdent { get { return $"SPPL-{this.ID:0000}" }} // untested`

Comment: Oh i see, i just tried it thank you @SeanLange

Comment: @nilsK Thank you also sir, for expanding my knowledge here. God bless all

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use a format string instead:

```
string ID = "SPPL-"
supply.lbl_id.Text = ID + i.ToString("0000");
```

Which will result in the format being applied correctly. Right now you are appending the `i` variable to the ID, which is already `SPPL-000`, so the next one becomes `SPPL-0001`, etc.

Comment: "There are *four* zeros!" - Picard

Comment: @Corak Course laid in captain

Comment: @RonBeyer Thank you sir